# Did not get my expected pay at the end of the month, what should I do?

Tags: salary, canada, salaried-pay, payroll

I started a new job back in May 2, 2022. Salaried - so I'm not really going by the hour. The pay schedule is semi monthly and on May 13th, I got my first pay check with the company. All good there so far.

And then on May 25th, I decided to file my resignation letter as I didn't think it was a good fit. I still worked May 16-24.

Today I was expecting to get my compensation for the 7 days that I still worked for this pay period but I didn't see any transaction in my back account.

I emailed my former boss about it but didn't get a response.

> Hi *(REDACTED)*,
>
> I hope all is well with you and the whole team.
>
> I was expecting to be paid for the 7 days that I still worked before I
> left my role at *(REDACTED)* (May 16-24) - but I didn't see any such
> transaction in my bank account. Can you tell me when I could expect to
> receive the amount?
>
> Thanks!

What should I do now?

### Update 1

I called the front desk, and asked for HR's phone number, apparently there isn't one. But they gave me the email address so I made contact with HR. Just waiting to get a response.

### Update 2

I just got a response from my previous boss and it looks like he's just waiting for the company equipment that I sent back before he approves my time.

Comment: Pick up the phone and call them already?

Comment: Pick up the phone. And do tell us the jurisdiction you're in, the country/state?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk remote work based in Ontario Canada, but I am from Alberta Canada. It's late to give my boss a call today, I'll try tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: If the phone call gets you nowhere, file a wage claim here: https://www.ontario.ca/document/your-guide-employment-standards-act-0/filing-claim

Comment: @StephanBranczyk thank you so much! I hope it doesn't get to that point as I don't want to burn bridges.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I talked to my boss about it and he told me I don't have to give any notice. I didn't think it was beneficial for the company to keep me for a few more days as I was still on probation and wasn't at full capacity yet.

Comment: I always find it interesting when employees are afraid of burning bridges while their employer already has set the bridge on fire and is enjoying the heat. There is nothing more serious than your salary and if it is delayed, the bridge is burned. Just be sure that it is actually delayed (according to your contract or local laws).

Comment: @DarkCygnus Apparently HR only has an email address and not a phone line. Just waiting to get a response.

Answer (score 1):

Send a physical letter (with copy by e-mail) via whatever service exists in your country that requires the recipient to sign to indicate receipt, stating that you believe you are due the money and will be in contact with your lawyer if you do not receive a response.

Note that at this stage there is no need to actual contact a lawyer, or even have one you might contact; you just want to establish a written record that you have made the request.

Comment: If it ends up getting to this point which I hope it doesn't. I don't think I have a way to prove my hours. As soon as I filed my resignation letter they removed my access from everything. Email, password manager, the time tracking app we used, etc. Would it still be feasible to bring in a lawyer?

Comment: How did you “work” if they revoked all your remote access?  That sounds a lot like “went ahead and fired you.”

Comment: @mxyzplk I worked only until May 24, I resigned on the 25th. Which they then removed all my access afterwards.

Comment: @mxyzplk Oh hold on, I think I know what you're asking - sorry I misunderstood. Yes if I can't prove my hours because they removed my access to the time tracker app then they can make it look like I didn't work those 7 days.

Comment: If they make it look like you didn’t work, but you worked, then we have fraud. That would be a much more serious problem for the company.

Comment: That said, it is very likely that payroll just made a mistake - they paid for the days you filled in, which Is correct 99.9% of the time, just not in your case, and they should fix that mistake easily as soon as they are informed. Fraud would be if they _knew_ you worked and took your missing timesheet as.a reason to claim you didn't work and not to fix the company's  mistake.